# Why is it that this function returns the literal type and making the return value type a tuple returns a general type?

Tags: typescript

I have a function that takes one argument and returns it as it is:

```js
function test<T>(input: T): T {
    return input
}
```

I found that if I pass a number or string, the returned type is going to be a literal type

```js
const res = test(1) // 1
const input = 1
const res2 = test(input) // 1
```

But if I slightly change the function to make it return a tuple:

```js
function test2<T>(input: T): [T] {
    return [input]
}
```

then the return type becomes just the `string` or `number` type:

```js
const res3 = test2(1) // [number]
```

So here I have two questions:

1. Why does the `test` function return literal types? Are there any resources I can read to learn this behaviour?
2. Why is it that wrapping the return value into a tuple solves this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why is the `test` function returns literal types? Are there any resources I can read to learn this behaviour?

TypeScript infers primitive types. You can read about function parameter type inference here:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#inference

> why is that wrapping the return value into a tuple solves this?

[TypeScript doesn't (yet) infer tuples](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48052)